# How to name input fields dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple of this div in my form generated dynamically by the user

```
<div class="property-container">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][id]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][name]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][stations][2][id]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][stations][2][name]">
 <input type="hidden" name="proposal[process][systems][1][stations][2][price]">
</div>
```

And this is how I name them using jQuery

```
    stationFieldsNames:function(station_container, system_id){
        var hidden = station_container.find('.property-container input[type=hidden]:first');
        station_container.find('.property-container').each(function(propCon){
        hidden.attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][id]');
        hidden.next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][name]');
        hidden.next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+propCon+'][id]');
        hidden.next().next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+propCon+'][name]');
        hidden.next().next().next().next().attr('name','proposal[process][systems]['+ system_id +'][stations]['+propCon+'][price]');
        });
    }
```

The problem I have with this is that I get duplicated field names. When I submit the form I see in the array that the data is missing. Where do I do wrong?

Comment: You want to set the same `system_id` in every property-container's input fields? That seems to be what you're doing. And do all property-containers have the first two inputs, as your code suggests it's only the last 3 that are specific to the property-container.

Comment: `system_id` is the function argument, it changes depending on user interaction. Yes, all propoerty-containers have first two inputs and the last three, as you said, are specific to the `property-container` but for some reason I get duplicate names. For example I never get 0 index like this `proposal[process][systems][1][stations][0][id]...`

Comment: Where is the form? How is it submitted? What fields are inside the `<form></form>` tags?